# "not Implemented by SQLite JDBC driver"

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have a database with User information, and I wanted to make a public static to return the database integers at any given time without having to make a void for every single one, but it's giving me this error:

```
0
java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.unused(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:466)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.executeQuery(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:506)
    at dysanix.main.checkUserColumnInt(main.java:726)
    at dysanix.main.main(main.java:50)
```

And this is my code:

```
public static int checkUserColumnInt(String column, String user) {
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Database.db");
            String query = "Select ? from userSettings WHERE user = ?";
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

            statement.setString(1, column);
            statement.setString(2, user);
            
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
            
            result.next();
            int columnResult = result.getInt(column);
            return columnResult;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Does someone understand what I'm doing wrong? I tried to Google things, but changing code around moved me from one error to the next... so I'm not really certain anymore at this point.

I am running JDBC driver sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar

Comment: Which SQLite driver are you using and which version?

Comment: Please note that, in your catch block, <e.printStackTrace();> never executed because of <return 0;>. Did you try to debug it? Do you get a valid connection object after the first line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`PreparedStatement.executeQuery(String sql)`](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/118288600bef15c4557cae901e73af3f14c80f7e/src/main/java/org/sqlite/jdbc3/JDBC3PreparedStatement.java#L534) is not implemented. I guess you just want to call `executeQuery()`. The query is defined by the `PreparedStatement` already.