# sqlite not implemented in JDBC Driver

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

Im trying to make an login code. The quick explanation is that i want to show the details of the account in a deatils page but i cant do that because an error always show that the function is not implemented in the JDBC Driver

```
JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String query = "select Username,Password from Login where Username=? and Password=?";
            try{

                PreparedStatement pst = connDB.prepareStatement(query);

                pst.setString(1,textFieldUN.getText());
                pst.setString(2, passwordField.getText());

                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                int count= 0;
                while(rs.next()){
                    count++;
                }
                if(count == 1){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Signed In");
                    frame.dispose();
                    Details details = new Details();
                    details.setVisible(true);

                    String qwerty = " insert into LoginTemp select * from Login where Username = ? ";
                    PreparedStatement psts = connDB.prepareStatement(qwerty);
                    psts.setString(1, textFieldUN.getText());
                    psts.executeQuery(qwerty);
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Username and Password Try again");
                }
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: What function? If you got a connection, the SQLLite driver is present. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: where is connDB defined ?

Comment: Show the error!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the problem is in `psts.executeQuery(qwerty);` because `PreparedStatement.executeQuery(String)` is not implemented in the SQLite JDBC Driver.

JDBC Driver Source code: [PreparedStatement.exequteQuery(String)](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sqlite/jdbc3/JDBC3PreparedStatement.java))

The `PreparedStatement.exequteQuery(String)` throws an `SQLException("not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver");`

This behavior is also described in the answer of [not Implemented by SQLite JDBC driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832605/not-implemented-by-sqlite-jdbc-driver%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/36832698/1317117) `PreparedStatement.executeQuery(String sql)` is not implemented in the SQLite JDBC Driver.

You can just use `psts.executeQuery();` resp. `psts.executeUpdate();`  without parameters here because the Query is already defined when you create the prepared statement.

Btw. ensure that you **always** close your `PreparedStatement`s and `ResultSet`s. 
For an explanation see [Do I need to close PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546592/do-i-need-to-close-preparedstatement)